# ChromeDriver is failing to consistently select correct item from List Box

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

In my application there is a list box wrapped in a span

span class="some class" unselectable="on">Please select an entity

```
  <li ...
     <dd class="some class" style="...." >Please select an entity</dd>
  <li ...
     <dd class="some class" style="...." >First Element</dd>
  <li ...
     <dd class="some class" style="...." >Second Element</dd>
  <li ...
     <dd class="some class" style="...." >last Element</dd>
```

I want to select a desired element from the list based on test case.

To achieve that I am clicking on the top element, which results in to expansion of the list. 
Then I am trying to find my desired element using dynamic xpath expression.
If I find the element, I perform a click operation on it. 
Then I go back and check if element is correctly got selected. 
The below code works very consistently (100%) on Firefox but its consistency on Chrome is about 40%. Any idea why it could be so?

```
public boolean SelectEntity(String EntityType) {

WebElement topElement = Driver.Instance.findElement(By.cssSelector("span[class=\"k-select\"]"));

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance, 3);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(topElement));
topElement.click();
String finalXPath = subXpathEntityNameFirstPart + EntityType+ subXpathEntityNameEndPart;

wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance, 3);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(finalXPath)));

WebElement listElement = Driver.Instance.findElement(By.xpath(finalXPath));
    if (listElement != null) {
        listElement.click();
        String selectedElementXPath = "//span[text()='" + EntityType+ "']";
        try{
                   WebElement selectedDropDownElement = Driver.Instance.findElement(By.xpath(selectedElementXPath));
                   if (selectedDropDownElement != null) {
                 return true;
                   }    
            } catch(Exception e) {
                 return false;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Please share the URL where you are seeing this!

Comment: Its an internal application so can not provide the URL.

Comment: Can you please create a demo webpage and post it here - Or else, it's really tough to get to the root cause!

Comment: I got to resolve this using Actions and it works perfectly well on Firefox and Chrome.
btnDropDown is the web element identified using xpath. 
`code`
Actions action= new Actions(Driver.Instance);

action.sendKeys(btnDropDown, uploadEntityType).build().perform();
`code`

action.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();